# Ошибка: the script don't inherit a native class that can manage

Tags: unity3d

Unity3d на все скрипты (и старые и даже только что созданные) отправляет ошибку

> the script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script unity

Comment: показывайте хоть некоторые из них.

Answer (score 0):

Класс должен наследоваться от `MonoBehaviour`. Значит у вас в скрипте это не сделано